# Integration of inverse trig function

Tags: integration, trigonometry

In the book this is the answer:

$$\int -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx = -\arcsin x + c$$

Can I also write that: $\displaystyle{\int -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx = \arccos x + c}$? If not, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both of the functions you wrote are particular primitives of the function $f(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

For the fundamental theorem of calculus, if two functions are primitives of $f(x)$ then they differ for a constant. If you try calculating the constant difference $C$ for these two functions, you will find out that $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$. You have just discovered a beautiful identity for inverse trig functions:

$$\text{arccos}(x)+\text{arcsin}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, because you forgot the constant. Even the answer in the book is not true (or, more likely, not written correctly), since

$$\int-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = -\arcsin x +C$$

and, because $\arccos(x) = -\arcsin(x) + \frac\pi2$, you can also write

$$\int-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \arccos x + C$$

Comment: Yeah, this books does not include constants. That is why I forgot mine above. Edited.